# Модели DTO, Entity и POJO

Tags: java, android, android-room

До сегодняшнего момента я использовал одни и те же модели и для записи в базе данных и для сериализации и как тело запросов на сервер. Во `fragment`ах и `Adapter`ах. То есть 1 модель везде в пакете `model` и не парился.

Но сегодня создавал модель для хранения в базе и возник вопрос:

В какой пакет закинуть класс -

1) `db > entity` или

2) `apiService > dto`

Понимаю, что в данном случае в `entity`, но если в запросах на сервер придется использовать?

Погуглил, везде говорят о разнице между ними. Но никто не показывает в реальных проектах
Поэтому пишу сюда, чтобы наверняка понять.

Вопросы:

1. Я один использую одну модель для всего, а все делают правильно, разделяют, дублируют похожие одни и те же классы, поля?
2. Если да, то как структурируете, как используете, можете поделится опытом из реальных проектов?
3. Реально ли оно того стоит, и почему использование везде - плохо?

Comment: Если вы собираетесь хронить в БД, то это определённо entity а не dto. То что у вас всегда эти сущности совпадают - большое счастье или вы что-то делаете всё же не то. Например отправляете больше данных, чем требуется

Comment: Написал: Понимаю, что в данном случае в entity, но если в запросах на сервер придется использовать?

Comment: Ну вот вам пример. У вас есть DTO и такая же сущность Entity. DTO возвращается и принимается от клиента. В один прекрасный день вы захотели оптимизировать вашу БД и разделили Entity на две таблицы. При этому DTO у вас останется прежним. Фактически вы скрыли от пользователя каким образом у вас хранится сущность в БД

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все зависит от задачи. В маленьком проекте вероятнее всего нет необходимости разбивать модели. Но если у вас проект большой то скорее всего вам стоит задуматься о том, чтоб создать разные сущности.

Для чего это делается? Ну вот смотрите, у вас есть API с которого приходят те или иные объекты. Эти сущности со временем могут меняться, и тогда вам придется менять их во всем своем проекте. Если же вы разделите сущности то вы абстрагируетесь от API и в случае чего вы измените только мапперы которые мапят API модели в Entity. К тому же таким образом вы можете в Entity хранить только те поля которые нужны вам для работы приложения. Либо задать в них какую-то свою логику, добавить свои поля.

P.S. Почти всегда вы будете дублировать поля. Но смысл этого в том, что у вас раздельные сетевые и локальные модели. Вы можете локальные модели конфигурить под свои задачи при этом сетевые модели никак не будут на это влиять. Единственное что может меняться это мапперы.

Более того иногда даже делают ещё и UI  модели. Которые хранят в себе только те поля которые нужны для отображения в пользовательском интерфейсе.

Но это совершенно не означает, что это надо делать всегда и везде. Это не является библией. Это просто один из способов разделять логику в больших проектах.

Например вы вполне можете не разделять сетевые модели и локальные, а сделать только UI и соответственно сетевые. Или вообще везде пользоваться сетевыми моделями или вообще найти свое решение.

Comment: Спасибо за детальный ответ. Можете привести пример из реального проекта? Как вы разделили 1 модель не сдублировав поля?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.